# How to make a Google query pull only TRUE values from two different columns

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am having trouble creating a query to pull only TRUE values from two specified columns. On the Data tab I only want data to populate in the query if either columns 10 or 11 contain TRUE values.  For some reason the query is pulling data that contains no True values in columns 10 or 11. The query also seems to only be reading values in column 10 and not column ll. If a user (Rep A or Rep B) selects a true value on in column 10 or 11 (checks box) I want those companies to populate on the Data tab.

Not sure what to try. Copy of workbook shared below.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14CxxGfL1XJX0hMH4G6N8Ghm6m1cHtYx-gfbL2tiJOOU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY({'Rep A'!A3:AC;'Rep B'!A3:AC},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col20 
  where Col10 = TRUE 
     or Col11 = TRUE", 1)
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BA1GuwezgGQhckNJ2__DGcKjOYJ_V-ywXTqPufgFtJ0/edit#gid=153384484)

Comment: Look s like it works for you but when I try to paste in the formula you created on my sheet it's not working for some reason. I unlocked the copy of the workbook I pasted above. Could you format my worksheet to mirror yours?

Comment: Thank you! What was I doing wrong? Also, how do I make the code drop to multiple levels like your answer above?

Comment: you can do it with CTRL+ENTER